# 404 not found error on Rails app with Helicon Zoo on Windows Server

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7, ruby-on-rails, http-status-code-404, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to run Rails App with Helicon Zoo on Windows Server 2008 R2. For the test case I used Redmine 2.3 that goes with the Helicon Zoo module.

Redmine has been installed successful, but it is available only from local network. I've configured port forwarding on my router to :80 port on my new redmine server.

When I'm trying to open it from external network (internet) I'm getting 404 "Not Found: /".

Same IIS configuration works fine for ASP.Net MVC Project.

How can I make this rails available from external networks?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure bindings in IIS are set correctly. Choose the site in IIS Manager and check if there is 
"Browse *:80 (http)" on the right.

Also, try to determine what gives our a 404 error - IIS or Rails.
If you need further assistance, please write to support@helicontech.com